# SQL stored procedure drop and create indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, indexing

I need to truncate a table to refresh data, however this table has an indexed view depends on it. I'm trying to drop indexes, then truncate table, then recreate indexes. I get an error that the non-clustered indexes don't exist or I don't have permission to drop them... code lives inside a stored procedure shown below. I am assuming it has something to do with the order of execution in the stored procedure as executing the code (drop/truncate/create) manually works.

```
DROP INDEX [IDX_VDetailEmergency] ON [dbo].[vFactEmergencySummary] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )
DROP INDEX [IDX_VDetailEmergency_facility_refno] ON [dbo].[vFactEmergencySummary] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )
DROP INDEX [IDX_VDetailEmergency_mode_of_separation_refno] ON [dbo].[vFactEmergencySummary] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )
DROP INDEX [IDX_VDetailEmergency_period_refno] ON [dbo].[vFactEmergencySummary] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )

truncate table DetailEmergency

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_VDetailEmergency] ON [dbo].[vFactEmergencySummary] 
(
    [facility_refno] ASC,
    [period_refno] ASC,
    [mode_of_separation_refno] ASC,
    [ed_visit_type_refno] ASC,
    [triage_category] ASC,
    [UDG_refno] ASC,
    [URG_refno] ASC,
    [URG_MDB_refno] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_VDetailEmergency_facility_refno] ON [dbo].[vFactEmergencySummary] 
(
    [facility_refno] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_VDetailEmergency_mode_of_separation_refno] ON [dbo].[vFactEmergencySummary] 
(
   mode_of_separation_refno ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_VDetailEmergency_period_refno] ON [dbo].[vFactEmergencySummary] 
(
   period_refno ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: You might want to *reconsider* having a **clustered index** on no less than **8 columns**! That'll never be very efficient, and it'll waste a lot of space, since all those columns are going to be replicated into each and every one of the non-clustered indices as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may follow these steps with SQL Server Management Studio if you are okay with dropping and recreating the table :

1. Right click on the database in which your table is available
2. Click **Tasks -> Generate scripts**
3. Press next to navigate to **Choose Objects**
4. Select **specific database objects**
5. Select your table
6. Press **Advanced**
7. Find **Script DROP and CREATE** in the list and change the drop down list as **Script DROP and CREATE**
8. Scroll down if you want to include Indexes or Constraints etc. in your script
9. Press **OK** and choose **Save to new query window** to see your script on a new query window
10. Press **Next** and **Finish**

Happy administrating!